# PL/SQL -- substitution variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using SQL Developer and writing this PL/SQL code, but I am getting error. Please help.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

ACCEPT name  prompt 'Name of employee'

declare
    v_sal NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_sal := &name;
    SELECT
        salary
    INTO v_sal
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE
        first_name = '&name';
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee ' || &name || ' has the salary' || v_sal);

END;

////

Error report -
ORA-06550: linia 4, coloana 14:
PLS-00201: identifier 'MOZHE' must be declared
ORA-06550: linia 4, coloana 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: linia 12, coloana 54:
PLS-00201: identifier 'MOZHE' must be declared
ORA-06550: linia 12, coloana 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: But, there's mo `MOZHE` within the code

Comment: Mozhe is one of the employee from employees table that I want to get

Comment: well, then substitute as `'&name'` and enter `MOZHE` *or* enter `'MOZHE'` as quoted as your variable is of string type.

Comment: Line 4 is pointless as well as bad syntax.  You want to set v_sal to '&name' but forgot the quotes, but why bother?  You just overwrite it again in the SQL.  Take it out.  Line 12 has the same syntax problem, put &name in single quotes.

Comment: `v_sal := &name;` makes no sense. v_sal is a salary amount.

Comment: The "current" error comes from the expression you want to print, using `dbms_output.put_line`. Since in the `where` clause you have hardcoded single-quotes around the variable, this suggests that you enter `MOZHE` without single-quotes for the variable. But then, in the concatenation in `put_line`, you have the variable **not** surrounded by single-quotes. So you are asking Oracle to concatenate `MOZHE`, not `'MOZHE'`. Then `MOZHE` must be an identifier of some kind (column name or alias, or a function with no parameters, etc.) Obviously that is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

ACCEPT name  prompt 'Name of employee'

DECLARE
    v_sal NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT salary
    INTO   v_sal
    FROM   employees
    WHERE  first_name = '&&name';

    dbms_output.put_line('Employee &&name has the salary' || v_sal);
END;
/
```

Comment: Everything it's working fine now. Thank you :)